# Replace twitter-like usernames in a model's attribute automatically in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I'm having a very hard time trying to figure out how to do this the MVC way. I have a `Comment` model which holds a `body` attribute. This attribute may contain mentions such as the following:

> Hi! This is me mentioning @someone.

Everytime someone posts a comment, an accessor method in the model converts all `@mention` to something like `#user:231#` where `231` would be the user's id. This way, if the mentioned user changes their username, I can still link & mention him without problems on older comments.

Now, I want to be able to access the `body` attribute and get the mentions already converted to links. It appears that doing this the MVC way, from within the model is not possible from what I have investigated.

Is there any easy way to do this? I don't wanna have to convert all the mentions on the controller because I think it could lead to repeated code and non-testable code.

Could anyone give me some advice on this?

Thanks!

Comment: im not sure why you would have to do this in the controller. just write a method on the comment model to process the text contained in the body to whatever you need.

Comment: The problem is that I can't access `link_to` and `user_path` from the model (technically can't and also that's not MVC "approved") =P

Comment: i think you'll want to look at `content_tag` and view helpers, where you can assemble html outside the controller. I wouldn't get too stuck on the mvc thing. keep your controller skinny, your views clear of logic and model access queries, and html out of your models, and you'll be doing good.

Comment: I don't think `content_tag` helps =S

Answer (score 1):

Parsing the message into a particular format and then re-saving it in the database where it can then be edited at a later date is silly. I'm sorry to be so blunt, but doing it this way is fundamentally broken for one major reason: when a user goes to edit the message later on, they'll see the formatted text **unless you format it back**. Do you really want to be responsible for doing this?

I would hope not. Because you're a programmer, you're naturally lazy and would like to do things in as few steps as possible.

What I would recommend doing to solve this problem is to parse the message when you display it on the page. Before you go screaming at me that this is computationally intensive if you've got a large amount of hits, hear me out. When it's displayed on the page, you can then cache it like this:

```
<% cache comment do %>
  # code goes here
<% end %>
```

This will store *the final output* in whatever cache you've set up with Rails, possibly Memcached or Redis, using a cache key which includes the comment's `updated_at` timestamp. Pay attention to this, it'll be useful later.

Retrieval from this cache will be faster than parsing it, and will be easier for you than to convert the message back and forth between its versions.

When a comment is updated, the `updated_at` timestamp will be different and so the new comment will be rendered first, then cached. In Memcached (so I'm told) it will clear the oldest cache key that hasn't been referenced if it needs more memory, thereby cleaning out the older comments.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In fact I was looking for how to cache stuff on the page (not just comments). Reparsing the comment to show it to the user is not that big of a deal, plus our users can only edit the comments 15 minutes after posting. Converting back and forward is just ~20 lines of code at most on the model, so converting is not much work for me (although it could be a little intensive being regexes, but caching takes care of that). Even if I didn't use changeable usernames, how could I convert them to links the MVC way?

Comment: I would have a helper that is called for the comment text and parses the names out and formats them correctly, with the output then being cached by the `cache` helper.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you end up mangling the original message? Let's say I originally posted:

"Hi! This is me mentioning @bob."

From what I understand, you want to store this as:

"Hi! This is me mentioning #user:1#"

Now, if bob were to change his username to "fred", my message would now look like this:

"Hi! This is me mentioning @fred"

It may be easier to simply store a many-to-many relation between messages and users it mentions. That way, you still can easily see which messages mention a specific user, but you don't need to mangle the original message to do so.

If you need to convert each mention into a link, you could order the entries in the relationship table in the same order that they appear in the message.

Comment: Mangling the message is not a problem (I even think twitter does this, though I'm not sure).

Comment: @Ian: No, Twitter wouldn't do this. It requires too much computation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this gem  help you https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text-rb

First, **include Twitter::Autolink** module from your class or helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include Twitter::Autolink
end
```

From views, you can call it by :

```
<%= auto_link("Hi @john_doe, welcome to #ruby") %>
```

it will generate link to twitter john_doe username and ruby hashtag